# Is it possible to get notification or event in a form when another form moves or closes

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, events

I am a newbie to c#. My application has 2 forms, say `Form1` and `Form2`. Whenever `Form2` moves, the `Form1` should perform an action.

**A traditional approach:**

I know I can have Form1 as a member of Form2 and manually call whatever method I need to do. But I don't like this approach. I want both the forms to be independent. And I want it to be scalable enough to add monitoring for move activities of Form2, like resizing, closing, etc.

**Custom Event raising:**

I came across this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/index) about raising events, but it is pretty difficult to understand and seems to be for creating custom events and sending the event whenever necessary. This seems a little better than the first approach but also similar in a way that I should send a custom event whenever an interaction with `Form2` happens. My requirement is more based on default events like location changed, closed, resized, etc.

---

Is there any way I could simply *subscribe* `Form1` to receive default events of `Form2`?

A pretty simple requirement I guess. Please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever Form2 moves, it raises the event [Control.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move(v=vs.110).aspx). You might also be interested in events LocationChanged and Resize.

Somehow your Form1 needs to know about the existence of Form2. For neat handling Form1 also needs to know when Form2 closes. So let's write the function that should be called when someone creates Form2:

In Form2:

```
void DependantFormCreated(Form otherForm)
{
    // this form needs to be notified whenever otherForm moves
    otherForm.Move += OtherFormMoved;
    // now whenever otherFormMoves, my function DependantFormMoved is called

    // this form also needs to be notified when otherForm closes:
    otherForm.Closed += OtherFormClosed;
}

private void OtherFormMoved(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
     Control otherForm = (Control)sender;
     Point location = otherForm.Location;
     ProcessOtherFormPosition(location);
}

private void OtherFormClosed(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    // other form does not exist anymore
    ProcessOtherFormClosed()'
}
```

Tip: in visual studio when you write the += after an event, press `<TAB>` twice. This will create the eventhandler function for you. If will have a signature similar to the ones above.

If you are not interested anymore in events from another class, simply use -=

```
this.OtherForm -= OtherFormMoved;
```

Therefor you need to remember which objects you subscribed to events.

If you create a class and you want to inform "everyone who might be interested" that something in your class is changed, or happened, just give your class an event and raise it whenever the item changes:

```
public MyPropertyType MyProperty {get; private set;}

public event EventHandler MyPropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnMyPropertyChanged ()
{
    // note: needs availability of null coalesence operator:
    this.MyPropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private SomeOtherFunction()
{
    this.MyProperty = ...
    this.OnMyPropertyChanged();
}
```

Quite often you'll see the following pattern. This way you are certain that every time that MyProperty changes, the event is raised:

```
private MyPropertyType myProperty = ...;
public MyPropertyType MyProperty
{
    get {return myProperty; }
    set
    {
         if (value != this.myProperty)
         {   // value changed: update + event
             this.myProperty = value;
             this.OnMyPropertyChanged();
         }
    }
}
```

Users of your class should do the following:

```
void Initialize()
{
    OtherClass otherObject = ...
    otherObject.MyPropertyChanged += this.ProcessMyPropertyChanged;
}

private void ProcessMyPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OtherClass otherObject = (OtherClass)sender;
     MyPropertyType value = otherObject.MyProperty;
     ProcessPropertyChange(value);
}
```

Only needed if you don't need the events anymore:

```
OtherClass otherObject = ...
otherObject.MyPropertyChanged -= ProcessMyPropertyChanged();

}
```

Derived classes should not subscribe to the event, but override OnMyPropertyChanged. The pattern makes sure that the derived classes get notified whenever the property changes before others get the event.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Form1` needs a reference to `Form2` and then it can listen to whatever events from it it likes - e.g. inside `Form1`:

```
public void RegisterForm2(Form2 form2)
{
    form2.SizeChanged += (s, e) => { /* handle resize */ };
    // same for other events
}
```

And then outside in your app where you create the forms:

```
var form1 = new Form1();
var form2 = new Form2();
form1.RegisterForm2(form2);
```